# print the adjacent sum sequence of integers in C without array

Tags: c, sequence

Is it in general possible to store a sequence of inputs and print it out later without using arrays?

I am required to take integer inputs sequentially with -1 marking as the end of input without taking it as an input (call it x<sub>n</sub>). Output is supposed to be sequence a<sub>n</sub> where

a<sub>n</sub>:= x<sub>n</sub>-1 + x<sub>n</sub>, where n>1

Following is my code, but the output happens along with the input and not at one go as the problem really requires. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int xo,a;
  int sum =0;
  int previous=0;
  scanf("%d",&xo);
  previous = xo;
  while ((!scanf("%d",&a)==0) && (!(a==-1))) {
    sum = previous+a;
    previous = a;
    printf("%d",sum);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Input:
1
2
3
4
-1

Output:
3 5 7

Comment: would you mind elaborating it more ? may be on some O/P sequence

Comment: "_but the output happens along with the input_" -- Move the `printf` outside the loop? And `!x==y` can be written as `x!=y`. Also, what do you expect as the output and what's the input for it?

Comment: Did you mean output as "3 5 7"?

Comment: ok, and what is this `previous = xo;` thing?

Comment: initializing the previous variable as the output sequence begins with n =2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but the purpose of your task could be to familiarise yourself with lists. Then you don't need an array to store the input values:

```
struct list {
  int val;
  struct list * next;
};
```

Handling lists should be abstracted into general functions:

```
struct list * list_add(struct list * lst, int val) {
  struct list * node =
      (struct list *) malloc(sizeof(struct list));
  node->val = val;
  node->next = lst;
  return node;
}
void list_free(struct list * lst) {
  while (lst) {
    struct list * temp = lst;
    lst = lst->next;
    free(temp);
  }
}
struct list * list_nreverse(struct list * lst) {
  struct list * nlst = lst;
  if (lst) {
     lst = lst->next;
     nlst->next = NULL;
     while (lst) {
       struct list * temp = lst;
       lst = lst->next;
       temp->next = nlst;
       nlst = temp;
     }
   }
   return nlst;
}
```

To use the list, you can either store your input values in the list or, to stay close to the code that you already have, calculate the output (the adjacent sum) on the fly and store that in a list, printing the entire list
at the end (in reverse order):

```
int current;
int previous;
struct list * output = NULL;
scanf("%d", &previous);
while ((!scanf("%d", &current) == 0) && (current != -1)) {
  sum = previous + current;
  previous = current;
  output = list_add(output, sum);
}
output = list_nreverse(output);
struct list * iterator = output;
while (iterator) {
  printf("%d ", iterator->val);
  iterator = iterator->next;
}
list_free(output);
```

*Note:* Code is currently untested, but should give you an idea of how you can accomplish this.

Comment: This doesnt check if `n>1`. Also include the print function.

Comment: Another improvement could be to use `typedef` for the struct as it probably makes code easier to write.

Comment: Yes, though I tend to avoid `typedef` for such short snippets, as I hope that it makes it easier to understand that these are pointers to instances of `struct list`. (And it makes it possible to understand the code even if you don't know about `typedef` (yet)). I also added the print function etc, took a while, I'm on mobile.

Comment: Oh, there is no need to check for `n>1`, the `n` is the counter of elements in his sequence declaration above. This is taken care of by asking for a value outside of the loop first.

Comment: I tested the code and it works as expected if you add the decleration for sum `int sum = 0;` at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep appending to a string. At the end of the input, print the string.

*a string can be considered as an array. maybe this invalidates this answer*

<s>Otherwise, no. You need an array to store either the input or the calculations.</s>
Oops ... as Daniel Jour says [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31200786/25324) you can use a list instead of an array.

Comment: Sir, in regards to the last line, we can take a pointer, keep reallocating, and populating. Technically, we'll be good, no? :-)

Comment: That is an array in my book :-)

Comment: But sir, pointers are not arrays, right? {_BTW, don't think I'm very serious_] :-)

Comment: right! **pointers are not arrays** and **arrays are not pointers**. But when you `malloc()` (or `realloc()`) you are obtaining a pointer to the first element of an *unnamed* **array**.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Can you give a solution using pointers. IMO declaring a string variable itself would require a char array.

Answer (score 0):

integer inputs are sequentially taken with 'scan'. To find end of the input, checking the scan return value with -1 so to scan the null element.

Here is my code as given below, output happens according to your requirement. output happens at one go that your problem really requires @subrat. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
 int xo,a;
 int sum =0;
 int diff=0;
 int previous=0;
 scanf("%d",&xo);   //dont need xo here :: use previous only
 previous = xo;
 while ((scanf("%d",&a)!=-1)) //important to use sum=0
 {
     sum = previous+a;
     previous = a;
     printf("%d ",sum);
     sum=0;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

**INPUT : 1 2 3 4 -1**

**OUTPUT : 3 5 7 3**